# POI running on TomCat causes loader constraint violation

Tags: java, excel, tomcat, apache-poi

I am trying to generate an XSLX using Apache POI, but get this error when trying to run my TomCat application:

---

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method

 "org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.PropertiesDocument.copy()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;" 

the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) 
of the current class, 
org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties, 

and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) 
for resolved class, org/openxmlformats/schemas/officeDocument/x2006/extendedProperties/PropertiesDocument, 

have different Class objects for the type ts.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.PropertiesDocument.copy()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject; 

used in the signature
```

---

I am using POI 3.15. The POI JARs are stored in the common Tomcat7/lib folder. (poi-3.15.jar, poi-ooxml-3.15.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar, xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar)

---

Can anyone help me explain what the conflict is here and how to resolve it?

Comment: Probably you have the same Jars in your Tomcat's lib folder as well as within your application's WAR/EAR. Remove the jars from either one of those places( i would recommend from inside your application) if this is the case and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the lightning reply :) No that was not it. The problem seems to be isolated to poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar. If it is in the lib dir I get the crash, if it is not I get the complaint about a missing class instead. I have tried running both with and without that jar in my war, but same result.

Comment: What happens when you have that JAR in your WAR/lib, but not in Tomcat's lib folder?

Comment: Don't add POI jar files to Tomcat's `lib` folder. Only add them to `WEB-INF/lib` of your webapp. In *general*, the only jar files you add to Tomcat's `lib` folder are JDBC drivers for Tomcat managed DataSources.

Comment: AH found it. I really want at least enough JARs in the web-inf to get the errors away from the Eclipse IDE. But when cleaning out everything besides poi-3.15.jar and poi-ooxml-3.15.jar, it seems that I get both a working IDE and a working run-time. Thanks a lot for the guidance guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the WEB-INF lib I had put pretty much all relevant JAR files. It seems that xmlbeans (and possibly more) caused the conflict when they went along with the WAR afterwards.

But when cleaning up so I only had poi-3.15.jar and poi-ooxml-3.15.jar in the WEB-INF/lib, I got a situation where both the Eclise IDE and the TomCat runtime worked.